# QPushButton attaches to Grandparent

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a main window for my application, and when a button is clicked, I have a slot to open a popup window:

```
void MainWindow::slotContinue()
{
    PopupWindow *pop = new PopupWindow(this);
    pop->show();
}
```

I pass `this` to the popup so that a button in the popup window can connect to the main window's slot.

```
PopupWindow::PopupWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(360, 100);

    contButton = new QPushButton("Continue", this);
    contButton->setGeometry(140, 60, 80, 30);

    connect(contButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), parent, SLOT(slotCalibrate()));
    connect(contButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
}
```

The popup window never appears. The continue button appears, but is part of the main window. The functionality of the button is fine. Upon clicking it, `slotCalibrate()` is successfully called and the button disappears, but I can't figure out why it is a child of what is supposed to be its grandparent.

If I don't pass `this` to the popup constructor the window appears but I can't connect the continue button to `slotCalibrate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PopupWindow` class inherits from `QWidget`, so it's not a window by default if it has a parent, it will be part of that parent, you need to set it to be a window:

```
void MainWindow::slotContinue()
{
    PopupWindow *pop = new PopupWindow(this);
    pop->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    pop->show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I was trying to use it the same way as my main window but of course that didn't have a parent widget.